# How to handle back press action in loopj/android-async-http

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, android-async-http, loopj

I am using this library `loopj/android-async-http` for performing network operation in android app. In the case of `AsyncTask` when you press back button while `asynctask` is running then you can cancel it `onBackPressed`. I want to know how this can be done in this library `loopj/android-async-http`.

In case of `AsyncTask`. We do like below

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mMyAsyncTask.cancel(true);
}
```

Do I have to handle this or loopj/android-async-http handles this automatically without I need to worry for this

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did in this way in the fragment & it is working fine for me.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // true specifies that even if the request is active it will be cancelled.
    if (asyncHttpClient != null) asyncHttpClient.cancelRequests(getActivity(), true);
}
```